# spring boot jsp : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/security/Escape

Tags: jsp, spring-boot

I am trying to add a simple jsp rendering in my spring boot application.

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {    
    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String loginMessage(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

resolver

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

and  /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp

I added both sprng boot web stater and tomcat embed

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper')
```

I am facing this issue

```
May 11, 2018 3:54:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/security/Escape] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.security.Escape
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by using compileOnly

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compileOnly('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper')
```

compile only is similar to scope provided in maven.